# Why is this procedure not working in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a homework assignment that calculates options for a cell phone plan. I created a module to hold my procedures to calculate things such as subtotal and tax. Although I believe my code is correct, whenever I call the procedure to calculate subtotal nothing happens, but if I post the procedure code into the Calculate event handler itself it works. Please review my procedure code and my procedure call in the Calculate click event

```
 Public Sub PhoneSubTotal()
    If frmIndividualPlan.radModel100.Checked = True Then
        decPhoneSubtotal = decMODEL_100
        frmIndividualPlan.lblPhoneSubtotal.Text = decPhoneSubtotal.ToString("c")
    ElseIf frmIndividualPlan.radModel110.Checked = True Then
        decPhoneSubtotal = decMODEL_110
        frmIndividualPlan.lblPhoneSubtotal.Text = decPhoneSubtotal.ToString("c")
    ElseIf frmIndividualPlan.radModel200.Checked = True Then
        decPhoneSubtotal = decMODEL_200
        frmIndividualPlan.lblPhoneSubtotal.Text = decPhoneSubtotal.ToString("c")
    End If
End Sub

Public Class frmIndividualPlan
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    PhoneSubTotal()

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I realize the code posted is not showing the "end class" but i can assure you that it is present in my code in visual studio

Comment: Assuming the PhoneSubTotal is in your module, 1 issue is going to be around access modifiers of the form controls.  A second issue is going to be around the use of frmIndividualPlan within that module.  frmIndividualPlan is the class name, but the module will require the actual instance of that class

Comment: As a general rule though, if the PhoneSubTotal sub requires being so closely coupled to the form there really isn't any benefit to separating it out like that, you could save yourself a few headaches by simply moving that sub into the code for the form

Comment: Thats probably what im going to end up doing. I only did it that way because the chapter the assignment is in the textbook involves using modules. i appreciate the help though thank you

Comment: @Hursey based on the name, it's a form, and thus has something in the nature of automatic instantiation via the class name.

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't make much sense to place code in a module if it is tightly tied to a single form. Modules are similar to a Static Class in C# and should be available to be called from anywhere in your project.

As a side note `frmIndividualPlan.radModel100.Checked` returns a Boolean. An `If` statement evaluates a Boolean so it is not necessary to add `= True`

It looks like there must be some constants defined somewhere for decMODEL_100 etc.

You can use a Module for a decoupled Function as follows.

```
Module Module1
    Public Function GetSelectedRadioButton(Container As Control) As RadioButton
        Dim rb = Container.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Checked = True)
        Return rb
    End Function
End Module
```

This function takes a `Control` as an argument. You would pass, probably, a group box such as `GroupBox1` or if the radio buttons are directly on the form, pass `Me` (yes, a form is a `Control`). The function then considers all the controls in the container that are radio buttons and finds the first one that satisfies `.Checked`). This is returned to the calling code.

```
Private decPhoneSubtotal as Decimal

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim CheckedRadioButton = GetSelectedRadioButton(GroupBox1)
    Select Case CheckedRadioButton.Name
        Case "radModel100"
            decPhoneSubtotal = decMODEL_100
        Case "radModel110"
            decPhoneSubtotal = decMODEL_110
        Case "radModel200"
            decPhoneSubtotal = decMODEL_200
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot identify selection")
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    lblPhoneSubtotal.Text = decPhoneSubtotal.ToString("c")

End Sub
```

There is an acronym about programming. DRY - Don't repeat yourself. You only need to assign `decPhoneSubtotal` to the label once.